# Textblock in Listbox not populating with values

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I am trying to populate textblocks within a listbox as shown below.

First I tried with this xaml which works fine.

```
    <ListBox Name="lbTodoList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ThisList1}"
             DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ListItem.Name}"
             >

    </ListBox>
```

When trying below however, nothing is shown in the textblocks

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=lbTodoList, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding ChangeCurrentView}">Click Me</Button>
    <Button Command="{Binding ChangeCurrentView}">Click Me</Button>
    <ListBox Name="lbTodoList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
             ItemsSource="{Binding ThisList1}"
             Width="200"
             >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Width="auto" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Path=ListItem.Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

cannot figure out what I am doing wrong here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Change Text="{Binding Path=ListItem}" to Text="{Binding Path=ListItem.Name}" - I think you missed a ".Name"

Comment: what irritates me most is that the topmost textbox is working as expected, displaying the selected listbox item :(

Comment: @togocoder - this does not work, sorry, I experimented away, think I am through all possible combinations there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to display a collection called `ThisList1` of object `ListItem`, you should define your model properly, here what you should do: 
Define the Item class:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    //add your properties
}
```

In your codebehind or Viewmodel define the collection that will be bond to the `ListBox`

```
    private ObservableCollection<ListItem> _thisList1=new ObservableCollection<ListItem>()
    {
        new ListItem()
        {
            Name = "Name1",
        }, new ListItem()
        {
            Name = "Name2",
        }
    }  ;
    public ObservableCollection<ListItem> ThisList1
    {
        get
        {
            return _thisList1;
        }
        set
        {                
            _thisList1 = value;                
        }
    }
```

finally here how to define the `ListBox`'s `DataTemplate`

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=lbTodoList, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding ChangeCurrentView}">Click Me</Button>
    <Button Command="{Binding ChangeCurrentView}">Click Me</Button>
    <ListBox Name="lbTodoList" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding ThisList1}"
         Width="200"
         >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock Width="auto" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Don't forget to set the `DataContext` using codebehind :

```
this.DataContext=this;
```

or via Xaml

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

And consider implementing the `INotifypropertyChanged` Interface to update the UI from the View Model automatically.

Comment: DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" - I was missing the datacontext... thanks, this was driving me mad - everyting else I had implemented already as described by you in detail. Bit more messy though :) Thanks again, much appreciated. Tough getting getting into wfp & mvvm, so many small things to consider